# Error with Magento Connect Manager

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, magento-connect-manager, downloader

When I click "Check for Upgrades" on Magento Connect Manager, following errors appear on system.log.

```
ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Connect_Package::importDataV1x() must be of the type array, boolean given, called in 
/downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Command/Registry.php on line 304 and defined  in /downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Package.php on line 1340

ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Connect_Package::importDataV1x() must be of the type array, boolean given, called in 
/downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Command/Registry.php on line 304 and defined  in /downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Package.php on line 1340

ERR (3): Warning: curl_setopt(): CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when an open_basedir is set  in 
/downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php on line 529
```

Anybody knows how to fix them?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I understand of this:

1. When you press "check for updates" it looks in your var/packages and the cache directory and processes what is there
2. It loads each xml file, and then it checks online for updates

I think importDataV1x is processing these xml files but one of the definition files in var/packages is messed up - does not match expected format

If you have access to it, I would have a look in var/packages - it would obviously be one of the recent ones.

Maybe looking at the files it might be obvious, one of them could be size 0. There could be a file for something you know didn't install...

Back them up then delete a few recent ones, see if it helps.

Another option might be to click "reinstall" on the suspect package.

**Be careful, as always with Magento Connect.**

Comment: I tried uninstalling every third party extensions from Magento Connect. But stil, when I go to Magento Connect Manager page, this appear. ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Connect_Package::importDataV1x() must be of the type array, boolean given, called in /downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Command/Registry.php on line 304 and defined  in /downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Package.php on line 1340

Comment: look on the server in your /var/packages directory - what's there?

Comment: now I use 1.9.2.4 and same situation. The files in the var/package directory are only Magento core files.